# Crashlitycs reporting wrong line number after kotlin migration

Tags: android, kotlin, crashlytics, google-fabric

Crashlytics reports showing wrong line number after migrating app to kotlin, i have already `-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable` in my proguard file

An example of wrong line number report:

http://crashes.to/s/419b5b28766

Comment: Is that from the version that's been migrated? The files are `java` so I don't think it is.

Comment: Its a library error in java, but both the java and kotlin files shows wrong line numbers: http://crashes.to/s/63aab3a5855

Comment: How far off is the line number?

Comment: A lot, always shows a low value like 1,2,11 etc, and the line is 200, 300 or so

Comment: Did you find a fix? I'm having the same problem. Interestingly, I upload my mapping file to the Google Play Console and the console reports the correct line numbers.

Comment: Also having same issue. Has anyone found the fix for this?

Comment: @JordyMendoza I've found the solution to this, posted as answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I disabled R8 and it worked fine, the line code on reports now shows the correct line number

Comment: Hey!  How did you generate the share link ie http://crashes.to/s/419b5b28766.
Can you please answer the question here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757870/how-to-get-publicly-accessible-crashlytics-report-url

Answer (score 4):

The thing is R8 is applying extra optimizations to save space using small integer numbers instead of real line numbers.

The problem with de-obfuscation appears when you try to de-obfuscate using the retrace script inside the Android sdk folder at: `/sdk/tools/proguard/bin/retrace.sh`

The version of the proguard inside the tools folder is 4.7 which is unable to de-obfuscate optimized line number stacktrace.

> The solution is to download the latest official proguard version
>   [here](https://github.com/Guardsquare/proguard/releases) and use the
>   retrace tool inside the bin folder, then the line numbers will be de-obfuscated correctly even with R8 enabled.
>   You can verify it manually with `latest_proguard/bin/retrace.sh mapping.txt stacktrace.txt`

Reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122752644

Comment: Issue tracking proguard upgrade is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150830809

Comment: Using proguard 6.2.2 does not fix this issue for Kotlin code. The only difference in the output is that the file names are converted from `.kt` to `.java`, yet the line numbers are still wrong.

Comment: Checked ProGuard 7.2.1 and it works, line numbers are correct.