# How to get publicly accessible crashlytics report url?

Tags: crash, crashlytics, crash-reports, google-fabric

I want to share my crashlytics crash report to  some 3rd parties.
How can I get a publicly accessible url like below?

http://crashes.to/s/419b5b28766

I am bit new here, is it a old deprecated crashlytics feature?
I don't seem to find in my fabric crashlytics dashboard.

Comment: I tried replacing the ID in that URL with the one when viewing a crash, no luck. Where did you get the URL from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zubair - from Fabric/Firebase. Great question. We deprecated that share link feature, so those won’t be accessible anymore. The decision to drop support for it was based on customer feedback, and because we don’t plan to carry over the share links feature over to Firebase.

Definitely not ideal if you were using that feature a lot, but as a workaround I recommend downloading the stacktrace and issue details with the "Download .txt" file button and sharing that instead.

Comment: Where is the "Download .txt" button? I upvoted the answer because it is accurate and informative but please add this to customer feedback: I thinks this is an useful feature and I would like it back.

Comment: Thanks- Bud. Downloading the stacktrace and issue details with the "Download .txt" file button was part of the Fabric.io. In Google Firebase, using the BigQuery is the best way to get that data. To to that make sure, you have enabled the BQ Integration under Project Settings > Integrations > BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the stacktrace and issue details with the "Download .txt" file button  was part of the Fabric.io. In Google Firebase, using the [BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export?authuser=0#what-data-exported) is the best way to get that data. To to that make sure, you have enabled the BQ Integration under Project Settings > Integrations > BigQuery